# prevent scaling of pattern in svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am facing a weird issue. I have a lot of patterns that I want to apply to all sorts of elements. They each have different sizes and they are flexible. The problem that I am facing at the moment is that when the elements that are filled with the pattern resize, their pattern scales with them. Instead I would like them to repeat their pattern. Here's a codepen demonstrating the behaviour:

https://codepen.io/thomassemmler/pen/oNwvJeX

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(2em, auto) [content-start] minmax(auto, 800px) [content-end] minmax( 2em, auto);
  grid-template-rows: 2em [content-start] auto [content-end] 2em;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    background-color: #151515;
    color: #ddd;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  grid-column: content-start/content-end;
  grid-row: content-start/content-end;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4em;
  background-color: #fff;
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    background-color: #222;
  }
}

.thing {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  &+& {
    margin-block-start: 2em;
  }
  svg {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &.a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  &.b {
    width: 80px;
  }
  &.c {
    width: 25px;
  }
  &.d {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2" stroke="currentcolor" />
</pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thing a">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
            <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#pattern)" />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thing b">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 80 80">
            <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#pattern)" />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thing c">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 80 80">
            <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#pattern)" />
        </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thing d">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 80 80">
            <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#pattern)" />
        </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried adjusting `patternUnits` & `patternContentUnits` but none of it works as expected. I face this issue specifically when trying to adapt one and the same element for different screen sizes.

I currently believe that I need to adjust the `viewbox` and the `width` & `height` of the element that has the `fill="url(#pattern)"` with javascript - but it feels *odd* to me. It feels that there should be a svg-only way to go about this.

Can I solve this in SVG only?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want say a small version to have fewer stripes but the same distance apart (in absolute terms) as the big version? So a very small square may have just one or two stripes? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that you can scale the `<rect>` and thereby control the pattern. Not that I'm able to explain in details why. In the CSS I set the width relative to the 100% and then scale the `<rect>` by the same fraction:

```
.d {
  width: calc(100% / 8);
}

.d rect {
  transform: scale(8);
}
```

I can imagine that you setup is a bit more complicated. I hope that you can use the tip.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(2em, auto) [content-start] minmax(auto, 800px) [content-end] minmax( 2em, auto);
  grid-template-rows: 2em [content-start] auto [content-end] 2em;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    background-color: #151515;
    color: #ddd;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  grid-column: content-start/content-end;
  grid-row: content-start/content-end;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4em;
  background-color: #fff;
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    background-color: #222;
  }
}

.thing {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.thing+.thing {
  margin-block-start: 2em;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.a {
  width: 100%;
}

.a rect {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.b {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
}

.b rect {
  transform: scale(2);
}

.c {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.c rect {
  transform: scale(3);
}

.d {
  width: calc(100% / 8);
}

.d rect {
  transform: scale(8);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2" stroke="currentcolor" />
</pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thing a">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 80 80">
      <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#pattern)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thing b">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 80 80">
      <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#pattern)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thing c">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 80 80">
      <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#pattern)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thing d">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 80 80">
      <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#pattern)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way of looking at it would be to decide on the 'base' size that you would like your pattern and have an SVG with that.

Then when you want to have a smaller version just use a clip-path to create it.

Rather hacky but might suit some situations.

Here's a snippet with your 100 dimension SVG clipped at 500px by 500px and by 100px by 100px.

```css
svg.big {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 500px 0, 500px 500px, 0 500px);
  position: absolute;
}

svg.small {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100px 0, 100px 100px, 0 100px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 520px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" class="big">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2" stroke="currentcolor" />
</pattern>
  </defs>
            <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#pattern)" />
</svg>

<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" class="small">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="4" height="4" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2" stroke="currentcolor" />
</pattern>
  </defs>
            <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#pattern)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is not a bad Idea but it won't help my case because the svg has a `width: 100%` and stretches. Even if it clips, it still scales.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that you wanted it exactly the same (in terms of distance between stripes) whatever the viewport size - I thought it just had to be consistent within a given viewport size. So, what is the absolute size you want things fixed at? I don't think that is specified anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is that you're specifying similar size viewBoxes for very different screen size rects. That means that the userSpaceOnUse units (which are specified in viewBox units) are different sizes as well.

One way to fix this - as chrwahl shows - is to use transforms to scale your rects after the pattern has been applied. Another way is to use a filter with a pattern defined inside an inline feImage, rather than a pattern to fill your rects.

Comment: The reason for why it behaves like it does makes entirely sense to me. I eventually had to solve my issue with javascript, but I was hoping I could do it without JS.

Comment: When I have a chance I will post code to show how to solve this with a filter - it just needs an inlined SVG - which always takes me a while to construct because it's a bit finicky